# My guard automatically embed to another method in controller Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

[image]

I created a bookmark method that uses a `JwtAuthenticationGuard` and `IdentifyRecipeGuard`. But when I put that method under another method that uses `IdentifyRecipeGuard`, for some reason `IdentifyRecipeGuard` gets executed when I try to make a request to the bookmark method. And when I move the bookmark method right under the `findOne` method it works well. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

When a request gets processed by your server the routes will be evaluated in the order that they are defined and the first one that matches will be executed. However, because `:id` comes first this controller method will be used and the request will never make it to your bookmark handler.

In your example, if someone sends a request to `/bookmark` then both the `:id` route and the `bookmark` route are potential matches (since the framework has no way of knowing that bookmark isn't the id of something).

To fix this simply move the more specific routes above the ones that have route parameters.

This issue is unrelated to NestJS and you would be seeing the exact same issue if you were building an app with Express directly